# Is there a word or an idiom for people who only spend their families' money and fool around?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, idioms, idiom-requests

Is there a word or an idiom for rich people who spend only their families' money and do not bother to work, just fool around?

Comment: "Wastrel" is the first to come to mind.  It's generally taken to mean someone who lives the high live off their inheritance while doing nothing productive (though the "official" definition is broader).

Comment: I call them "income redistribution vectors."

Comment: I just call them bums.

Comment: The old British slang of a "dandy" comes to mind - referring to the problematic youths of England using inherited money for wasteful and dangerous activities in the English countryside.  It's the basis for the Mr. Toad character from "[The Wind in the Willows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wind_in_the_Willows)" and the Disney short film "[Mr. Toad's Wild Ride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Toad's_Wild_Ride)".

Comment: At Mexico we call them "Juniors"

Comment: Related: [Natalia Nezvanova's piece](https://www.quora.com/How-much-does-your-monthly-salary-need-to-be-to-make-you-upper-class/answer/Natalia-Nezvanova)

Comment: Wouldn't that be a 'playboy'?

Answer (score 59):

They are known as ***"trust-fund babies"*** or ***"trust-fund kids"***:

from [Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trust-fund%20baby).com:

> noun:  a child of wealthy parents or other relatives who can rely on a trust fund rather than hard work for a living

Comment: If they assume a counter-culture lifestyle there is **"trustafarian"**, which I've always thought had a nice ring to it.

Comment: @dmckee a nice ring... of smoke... gotta treat that glaucoma and stress of living up to mommy and daddies expectations after all

Comment: Gadabout? Not really I guess.

Comment: I looked up "gadabout", too, @PaulD.Waite, before posting my answer.  They are habitual pleasure-seekers and have wanderlust for travel but it doesn't say anything about they're sponging off their parents' money.  So in my interpretation, you can be a "gadabout" and not fill the OP's example qualifications.

Comment: Good answer, Kristina. Amazingly (for such a popular phrase), I've never encountered it previously.

Comment: The troubles with this otherwise very good answer are that (1) not all wealthy people set up trust funds for their wastrel children (think Warren Buffett) and (2) not all trust-fund beneficiaries engage in wasteful, self-indulgent, indolent behavior (think Nelson Rockefeller).

Comment: I agree @HStephenStraight, but I don't really hear responsible offspring of the very wealthy called "trust fund babies".  I think, maybe erroneously, that those of us without trust funds, assume that the offspring of the very wealthy *must* have trust funds, so that the name is used without actual knowledge of the source of their money, though it's probably fair to say that the source of their money is their family.

Answer (score 35):

Traditionally the most common (**noun**) terms for such a one would probably be a **"prodigal"** (*as in the proverbial, Prodigal Son*) or, alternately, a "**profligate**".

> **prodigal** *noun*:
>
> **1**. a person who spends money in a recklessly extravagant way.
>
> • a person who leaves home and behaves recklessly, but later makes a repentant return.
>
> *noun*: **prodigal son**
>
> synonyms: wasteful, extravagant, spendthrift, ***profligate***, improvident, imprudent; see Google [prodigal](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=prodigal+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=prodigal+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.8.7918686...........0.a4YlKHAVnrw&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **profligate** *noun*:
>
> **1**. a licentious, dissolute person. "he was an out-and-out *profligate*"
>
> *synonyms*: libertine, debauchee, degenerate, dissolute, roué, rake, sybarite, voluptuary

see Google [profligate](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=profligate+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=profligate+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l4j0i22i30.0.0.0.11395...........0.nkSEDVnMVvU&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: this was the first word that came to mind.  great choice.

Comment: I immediately thought Prodigal Son as well. Like the Good Samaritan, the parable is so well known that it would almost certainly be understood by the religious and the non-religious alike.

Comment: I think OP wanted a noun rather than an adjective?

Comment: @AndyT - yes, I only just realized that though I'd used the noun-form in my preface I'd only included the adjectival in my definitions. Please excuse the oversight - the nouns "prodigal" & "profligate" are the intended suggestion.

Comment: Nice words, indeed, but none of them means:  rich people who spend only their families' money. Jus' sayin'.

Comment: @Jim Reynolds – my suggestion of the noun “prodigal" isn’t exclusively referencing the dictionary definition of one who is “wastefully extravagant,” but also connotes to the parable of the prodigal son from Luke 15:2 of the Christian New Testament. Are you familiar? This prototypical prodigal---the younger of two brothers of a wealthy sire---took family money into the local red-light district and blew it all on wine, women, and song, or so the exegesis goes. Seems pretty close to “rich people who spend only their families' money and do not bother to work, just fool around.”

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar. The term *prodigal* is often bound to *son*, but the primary meaning is not exactly "to spend one's family's money and not work, and to 'fool around'". The definitions for *prodigal* in dictionaries focus on wastefulness, lavishness, and of relating to the biblical parable, which itself focuses mainly on redemption, secondarily on foolish, extravagant spending of an inheritance given by a father to a son. I think it's interesting that, so far, no one has found a word or idiom expressing that precise meaning.

Comment: I didn't mean to be as critical as I may have come across. I looked at all the  answers so far, and I'm impressed that there seems to be no exact word or phrase to express what the OP says. Many readers see value in your answer, and as I sincerely wanted to say: nice words. I also think it's interesting that we don't have anything that is directly responsive. The key concept I get from the OP's words are about being parasitical and dependent. I don't think the concept of self-reliance or independence from family was common in Jewish culture 2,000 years ago!

Comment: I agree with @JimReynolds comments about "prodigal" but love the word "profligate"!  Profligate trust fund kid is exactly how I would describe someone as described by OP.

Comment: I like both of these words, @Ell. But what's interesting here, is that the OP never suggested that the person they wish to describe spends a lot of money or that the person *necessarily* spends money on "debased" things, as these words suggest. I suppose we don't know what the OP means by "just fools around". It could mean spends tons on (maybe) alcohol, drugs, behaves wildly and engages in vice, or alternatively, just plays computer games or lolls around watching TV. The most interesting thing to me is that it seems we have not found anything yet that captures the idea with just the right +

Comment: levels of generality and specificity to match the OP's question as written. And the *reason* I think this is interesting is that the phenomenon should be common enough (and sufficiently evocative of emotion and drama), that I'd have expected for there to be many just-right terms. We have many if we use phrases (leeches off her family; lives off his parents; bums off their family, and many synonyms), and we have great words such as those given above WHEN THEY FIT. But they all need to be constructed as such as far as I know, and as far as I can see from all of the answers given so far.

Answer (score 25):

Indeed there is: **"spendthrift"** is one, and **"wastrel"** another. The latter is archaic but I really like it. Derived from "waste", I guess, but pronounced with a short A not a diphthong. You don't have to be stinking rich to be these, though. And there is another archaic word for spending an inheritance etc. quickly and reprehensibly: "to blew". That's not the past tense it looks like, because the past is "he blewed it all". National Lottery please note. No noun that I know of, though.

If your emphasis is not on blewing the money but just being a **rich layabout**, then, well, Bertie Wooster was a member of "the Drones Club". I think the British "Hooray Henry" and "Sloane Ranger" might fit. The American equivalent would I think be **"trust fund babe"**. (Of which the masculine is what? I don't know,) Less demotic is "the idle rich".

Comment: Do you have a source for that use of "blew"?  I've heard "he blew it all" but not "he blewed it all".  And it's not "trust fund babe", it's "trust fund baby" - though I'm sure some trust fund babies are babes! :-)  Finally, "spendthrift" and "wastrel" are good words for someone who spends money foolishly, it doesn't really address that it's their family's money and that they don't work, just fool around.

Comment: @Kristina. Yes, I do. I educated myself in my childhood on the complete short stories of H.G. Wells, a beautiful leather volume that my father got at a school prizegiving. One story was about this guy sucking up to a rich uncle and messing up so that another relative got it. Next sentence "And he blewed it, he blewed it all." Stuck in the mind for 50 years!

Comment: No doubt it's a memorable expression (and I also love H.G. Wells!) but the Oxford Dictionary is not finding it in either the US nor the BrE version so I suspect it's a slangy or dialect version of "he blew it".

Comment: @Kristina: Wells did after all pioneer Cockney diction in literature, did he not? So I take your point. Which Oxford? I used to have the OED, the wall-length one, in micro format: the whole shebang in one volume, honest. But my eyes got too old to cope with it, even with the magnifying glass, so I gave it to a younger friend. Gotta crawl under the mosquito netting now, good night.

Comment: Nothing so elegent, David, just the online version: www.oxforddictionaries.com/us - which also cross-referenced the word (blewed) in their other language versions

Comment: I don't think "babe" is feminine. If it sounds so, say "baby."

Comment: I think the "blewed" here is not a past tense of some hypothetical verb "to blew", but just an alternate form of the past tense of "to blow".

Comment: @Sumelic: I have seen it in the other tenses too. Invented example: "He is the sort who cannot be trusted not to blew anything he gets". But as Kristina pointed out, it might be dialect or early twencen slang, and as I agreed, Wells used plenty of both. What I don't accept is that he made it up out of whole cloth, or was ignorant of the language.

Comment: "Wastrel" is not pronounced with a short A, as a quick check of a dictionary would show.

Comment: @mikeagg I've always heard "wastrel" pronounced with a short A as well. Is it a regional thing? I have lived  in western US my whole life (read Colorado/Wyoming area).

Comment: Of the 5 on-line dictionaries I have checked, 4 only have the conventional pronunciation "weɪstr(ə)l".

Comment: Merriam-Webster Online has the alternative *wäs-trəl* ("woss-trul"), but no alternative like "wass-trul" with a short A.

Comment: Is _spendthrift_ really an answer? It's someone who spends lots of money, but it's not necessarily inherited.

Comment: @Barmar: No, but it's not necessarily not, either. If you blow your inheritance on the horsies, I reckon you qualify.

Comment: I interpret questions like this as looking for a word that's pretty specific to the type of person decribed. E.g. if you say "He's an X, the listener would understand that he's living off his inheritance rather than working for a living." Also, couldn't he live frugally, so his inheritance will last longer?

Comment: @Barmar: I was on an airplane all night so my brain has gone on strike. I can't get my mind round this issue today, which is not he same as contradictinf what you say. My previous incarnation Arthur Schopenhauer did exactly what you say, lived all his life on a smallish inheritance, being very frugal in lodgings.

Comment: @David Pugh: Sure, but a spendthrift could equally well be blowing his own earned money on horses*.  See e.g. many pro athletes & other celebrities.  *Betting on them: owning horses can be a perfectly reasonable lifestyle choice, and one conducive to frugality in other areas of life :-)

Answer (score 16):

*[Playboy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/playboy)*:

> noun
>
> A wealthy man who spends his time enjoying himself, especially one who
> behaves irresponsibly or is sexually promiscuous:
>
> *ODO*

Apparently the phenomenon is not chauvinistic as *[playgirl](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=playgirl)* works for her:

> n.
> A usually wealthy woman who spends much of her time
> pursuing leisure and romance.
>
> *ODO*

The popularity of *Playboy Magazine* (and its sister Playgirl) has reinforced the sexual connotations of this expression to the point of dominance, but everyone understand intuitively that casual sex can be a very expensive habit.

Comment: Someone can be a Playboy or Playgirl and not necessarily be spending their *family's* money as the OP's example states.

Answer (score 12):

I've always liked the term [Trustafarian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trustafarian), a portmanteau (of trust and rastafarian) that can be somewhat limited in distribution to college campuses and the "hip" parts of town *(and it is a term which can seen as a form of religious and cultural expropriation from the Rastafaris).*

> /ˌtrʌstəˈfɛərɪən/
>
> noun
>
> 1. (sometimes capital) ( Brit, informal) a young person from a wealthy background whose trust fund enables him or her to eschew conventional
>      attitudes to work, dress, drug taking, etc
>
> Word Origin C20: from trust
>   (fund) + ( Rast) afarian
>
> *from dictionary.com*

There's even a book [The Trustafarian Handbook: A Field Guide to the Neo-Hippie Lifestyle - Funded by Mom and Dad | Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1440502153)

Comment: I would assume a *Trustafarian*, like *Rastafarians*, was prone to smoking pot (and by extension, maybe doing other drugs), and not just spending money.

Comment: And all this may explain the curious phenomenon of so many white frat boys obsessed with Bob Marley.

Comment: This is somewhat demeaning to actual Rastas (which is a real religion)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: it demeaning and is a form of religious and cultural expropriation; that's my point. Rastafari is a real belief system which encompasses Christian thought. And Rastafarianism is a term not much appreciated by Rastafaris.

Answer (score 9):

*[Rake](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rake)* is not as overwhelmed with sexual connotations as *playboy* but it still:

> rake 2
>   n.
>   A usually well-to-do man who is *[dissolute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dissolute)* or promiscuous.
>
> *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.*

It is the reduction of *[rakehell](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rakehell)*:

> n.
>   An immoral or dissolute man.
>
> *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.*

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=rakehell&searchmode=none) suggests it is someone *racing to hell*:

> 1540s, possibly an alteration (by association with rake (n.1) and
>   Hell) of Middle English rakel (adj.) "hasty, rash, headstrong,"
>   probably from raken "to go, proceed,"
>   from Old English racian "to go
>   forward, move, hasten," of unknown origin.
>   Compare rakeshame (n.) "one who lives shamefully" (1590s).
>
> *Etymonline.com*

Although it is denoted as a *man*, it would welcome gender neutrality in our liberated libertine world.

Comment: [relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5H5r4_CoJo).

Comment: Yeah, LOL! @erich

Comment: Maybe this comes from excessive exposure to folk song, but the immediate association in mind from 'rake' or 'rakeishness' is of sexual promiscuity. Whereas a playboy is only incidentally so.

Comment: It is interesting, @DominicCronin, how individual connotations of words can vary significantly--particularly words that are not terribly common. Which folk song would you be referring to?

Comment: Pretty much the whole genre. If a young woman says she fears her suitor is a rake, we all know what she's suggesting. There are also examples of female rakish Ness.

Comment: You probably guessed, my last comment got mangled by my telephone. I meant "rakishness".

Answer (score 6):

A *dilettante* is a dabbler in different subjects, usually the arts. The usage of dilettante peaked in American literature in the [1920's to the 1940's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dilettante&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdilettante%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdilettante%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDilettante%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDILETTANTE%3B%2Cc0). This is because in those hard times a dabbler needed to be wealthy in order to have the luxury to avoid an onerous or practical occupation.

The word *dilettante* conjures up a mental picture of an idle, well-off person who has free time and can afford to shift focus from one notion to the next. Necessarily having great wealth isn't part of the dictionary definition of the word. However, I have almost always seen it used to describe rich or decadent people or goods.

There are quite a few wealthy individuals described as dilettante. Using Google Scholar, I identified quite a few. The implication is that the individuals' wealth permits this lifestyle.

A café using the word [Dilettante](http://www.dilettante.com/Mocha-Cafes/Mocha-Menu.html) to present as upscale is a modern example. "The Expression of Elegance." Indeed. They sell coffee.

The Dilettante is a pricey car in the video games Grand Theft Auto IV and V.

(I don't have the reputation to post more than 2 links or I would have more citations.)

Answer (score 5):

In a somewhat restricted context, the term
**remittance man** might apply.
The term was used in former times (such as the Victorian era) 
to describe British men who lived abroad and whose income
consisted of funds sent by their families.

While this does not necessarily imply that the remittance man
was simply fooling around rather than trying to work,
there is a connotation that the remittance men were being paid to stay
far away from their families in order to avoid embarrassing them,
e.g. by dissolute behavior.

The term is old-fashioned but could be used as a metaphor
for a modern (and not necessarily British) lifestyle.
I think the term **remittance woman** would be understood as
a female form of the same term.

Since the original term described people who received income at
someone else's discretion and who were kept socially distant from
their wealthy families, I would find it difficult to apply to someone
who had the unfettered ability to spend the wealth accumulated by their family
or who was permitted to participate in the family's social circle.
That is, I think that in order for the usage of the term to make sense,
it would need to be more restrictive than the usage of terms
such as *playboy* or *idle rich*.
But in the right context I think it might be used with good effect.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase I've heard is "idle rich".

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  I like that suggestion; can you provide an example sentence and/or provide any links to show evidence of use?

Comment: I've seen it mostly as a TV trope. [Idle Rich](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IdleRich)

Answer (score 3):

*[Dissolute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dissolute)* would be a good adjective:

> (Of a person or a way of life) overindulging in sensual pleasures:
>   *unfortunately, his heir was feckless and **dissolute***
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 3):

Freeloader is what came to mind immediately.  Definitely negative connotations, and not necessarily required that the contributing family is rich.

Answer (score 2):

How about "trust-fund squanderer"?

Answer (score 0):

"rentier"  -- "An individual who receives an income, usually interest, rent, dividends, capital gains, or profits from his or her assets and investments." (Wikipedia dictionary).  Note that this is not **necessarily** from family money -- but it does have old money connotation.   More importantly, if you insist on the "fooling around" part, "rentier" does not imply idleness or frivolity, it just specifies the source of income.

Answer (score 0):

### Woosterish

A Woosterish person behaves like the fictional character [Bertie Wooster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertie_Wooster).

> Bertram Wilberforce "Bertie" Wooster is a recurring fictional character in the Jeeves novels of British author P. G. Wodehouse. An English gentleman, one of the "idle rich" and a member of the Drones Club, he appears alongside his valet, Jeeves, whose genius manages to extricate Bertie or one of his friends from numerous awkward situations.