# Single word for money-waster

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who wastes money could be called a ____.

I saw this article that made me want this word, I can't believe governments are spending like 100x consumer price per unit.

> Government workers are professional ______s.

I have considered "splurgers", but that seems more like throwing money around, and doesn't have strong enough connotations of being wasteful.

Maybe a synonym for prodigal? It feels weird to me to use prodigal as a noun, even though it can be one. But I would definitely associate the word I want with a rich son showing off his wealth, like playboy style. Like the *Batman Begins* scene where Bruce Wayne rolls up to the hotel in his million-dollar car with his foreign escorts, and then buys the hotel so carelessly because he got told off that his escorts were bathing in the water fountain centrepiece.

I want a word that means, this is a person who spends lots of money, without caring at all about whether they are getting appropriate value for it. They expend no effort at all in fighting for a fair price or doing market research, they are happy to let themselves get conned, they don't care at all if they're being charged thousands of times production costs, they waste money like whatever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A single word for someone who spends their wealth very foolishly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107611/a-single-word-for-someone-who-spends-their-wealth-very-foolishly) ////////// (and [many others here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-request%5D+spendthrift)) :)

Comment: [spendthrift](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spendthrift)

Comment: Profligate. Look it up.